# Right way to access fields of an abstract class?

Tags: java, oop, abstract-class

I am trying to figure out what is the right way to access private fields of an abstract class and then use it in the class which is extending the abstract class.

Below is my abstract class

**Process class (abstract):**

```
public abstract class Process implements Runnable {
  private final Properties props;
  private final String processName;

  public Process(String processName, Properties props) {
    this.processName = processName;
    this.props = props;
  }

  public abstract void shutdown();

  public Properties getProps() {
    return props;
  }

  public String getProcessName() {
    return processName;
  }
}
```

And below is one way of how I am extending my above abstract class and using `props` Properties object.

**ProcessA class:**

```
public class ProcessA extends Process {
  private ProcessConsumer<byte[], byte[]> consumer;

  public ProcessA(String processName, Properties props) {
    super(processName, props);
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    // is this the right way?
    String processName = getProcessName();
    Properties props = getProps();
    consumer = new ProcessConsumer<>(props);

    // .. some other code with try catch block
    // using processName and consumer
  }

  @Override
  public void shutdown() {
    consumer.wakeup();
  }
}
```

And below is second way of how I can extending my above abstract class and using properties object.

**ProcessB class:**

```
public class ProcessB extends Process {
  private final ProcessConsumer<byte[], byte[]> consumer;

  public ProcessB(String processName, Properties props) {
    super(processName, props);
    // is this the right way to use props object?
    this.consumer = new ProcessConsumer<>(props);
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    String processName = getProcessName();

    // .. some other code with try catch block
    // using processName and consumer
  }

  @Override
  public void shutdown() {
    consumer.wakeup();
  }
}
```

I want to use `props` Properties in making `ProcessConsumer` object but I am confuse what is the right way to use `props` object? Should I call `getProps` method on abstract class inside my run method and then use it? Or just take it in the constructor and build it there?

What is the difference and what is right way?

Comment: The point of private is that it is not accessible anywhere but from the code in the class itself, not in extended classes or other classes. If you do want to  be able to access it, you should make it protected. Better to make some kind of protected or public accessor though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

both of your solutions would work.
But I would use a completely other solution:

```
 public abstract class Process implements Runnable {
    private final Properties props;
    private final String processName;

    public Process(String processName, Properties props) {
        this.processName = processName;
        this.props = props;
    }

    protected abstract void shutdown();
    protected abstract void run(String processName, Properties props);

    @Override
    public final void run() {
        run(processName, props);
    }

}

public class ProcessA extends Process {
    private ProcessConsumer<byte[], byte[]> consumer;

    public ProcessA(String processName, Properties props) {
        super(processName, props);
    }

    @Override
    public void shutdown() {
        consumer.wakeup();
    }

    @Override
    protected void run(String processName, Properties props) {
        consumer = new ProcessConsumer<>(props);
    }
}
```

So the Process only have one public Method,
you make the run method final, so no one could override it.
You get the params in the other run method.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. What is the benefit with this approach?

Comment: The Sub class ist not able to override the getProps and the getProcessName Method.

Comment: The Sub class ist not able to override the getProps and the getProcessName Method. Think of Process <- ProcessA <- ProcessAA, what if Process AA will override getProps... In this Solution this is not possible. Its open for extention but colsed for modification. (Not in the sense the open/closed principle means.)

Answer (score 2):

When you extend an abstract class, the sub-class inherits the private fields BUT they are not accessible for them. Because private fields are only accessible withing the scope of the class they were defined in.

So to initialize the private fields you use `super`, as well for accessing them. You can look at `super` as the mother of `this`:

```
public abstract class AbstractProcess{
    private final String processName;
    public AbstractProcess(String name){
        processName = name;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return processName;
    }

}




public class MyProcess extends AbstractProcess{

     public MyProcess(ProcessName name){
        //like you did is true
        super(name);

     }

    //now to access them
    public String getName(){
        return super.getName();
    }

}
```

Also you can walk-around this whole private+inheritance thing by using `protected` . A `protected` field is like a private `field` but is inherited AND accessible by sub-classes. So you could just call `this.someProtectedField` (notice it's not a "getter" function) instead of `super.getSomePrivateField()`

I hope this is what you are asking about and that I made it clear enough.

Comment: This is not what I am asking. My question was how to access `props` of my abstract class in my subclass. Should I call get method on abstract class and then use it in my run method? Or should I just use it in the constructor as soon as it was passed in my subclass.

Comment: use `super.getProps()`. Having defined a method called `getProps()` in the super class that returns the props. I gave an example about `processName` but you can use the same for props

Comment: you mean to say in my run method of `ProcessA` class, this line `Properties props = getProps();` should be `Properties props = super.getProps();`

Comment: Yes that should do

Comment: Ok so now what is the difference between this what you suggested vs what I did in `ProcessB` class. As you can see in my  `ProcessB` class, I am using `props` object directly in the constructor (which is passed) and building my `ProcessConsumer` right there only. Which is right?

Comment: In `ProcessA` class I was making my `ProcessConsumer` object inside run method by calling `super.getProps()`.

Comment: What you did in process B would work too, but if you needed `props` elsewhere in your class you will not be able to get it unless `ProcessConsumer` has a `getProps()` or you'd again have to use `super.getProps()`. But looking inside `run()` , `getProcessName()` will not work you'll need `super.getProcesssName()`